# unable to run perl scripts in BASH "Cannot Locate Switch.pm"

Tags: bash, perl, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run perl in my bash terminal by typing

```
perl helloworld.pl
```

but when I try to do this an error message comes up.

> Can't Locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch
>   module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2-level
>   ....)BEGIN failed --compilation aborted at...

I've tried updating Switch.pm using CPAN but it either says it can't install because missing YAML module, (I installed that too.. and nothing), or it says its installed but then the same error message comes up.

I'm using Yosemite on my mac. If anyone has run into this or knows where I can find a solution that'd be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: YAML is used `cpan` to collect stats if it's there. There's no harm is missing it, and it's definitely not why the installation of Switch is failing.

Comment: Most people strongly recommend avoiding Switch since it's based on a source filter, which makes it inherently fragile. This can result in very weird and hard to debug errors.

Comment: Please provide the output of `which perl ; which cpan ; head -n 3 "$( which cpan )" ; echo "o conf" | cpan | grep arg ; perl -E'say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV'`

Comment: I am using LinuxOS which is similar to MacOS. Usually when I am installing a module through CPAN. Have you tried that? Here is a sample video [Installing Perl Module from CPAN into MAC ][1] that shows you the process on MacOS. If yes show us some output of the errors.


  [1]: http://Installing%20Perl%20Module%20from%20CPAN%20into%20MAC

Comment: What does `helloworld.pl` look like? Running @ikegami's code would be a huge help in figuring out what's going on, if you can provide that!

Comment: @Gaurav, Just pretend it's `use Switch;`

Comment: You can try to install corresponding library(`libswitch-perl`) from repo and it will work. I use to do same way on my debian machine.

Comment: @shivams: A Debian solution is unlikely to work on a Mac :-)

Comment: @DaveCross yeah i know that. What i meant to convey via my comment is that there might be library for switch on mac which you can try.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that Switch.pm was first included with Perl's standard distribution with Perl 5.8.0. It was deprecated in Perl 5.12.0 and removed from Perl 5.14.0 (I got those values by asking [corelist](http://perldoc.perl.org/corelist.html) and translating dev version numbers to the next production release). So I guess you're trying to use a version of Perl that is more recent than that. We'll be able to help more if you tell us how you tried to install the module and *exactly* what error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

Switch.pm is deprecated and no longer distributed with the core modules.

You should not use it in production code if you have the option.

Comment: It won't run the script either way. It says I need to install Switch.pm and it doesn't run it.

Comment: the best option you have is to edit helloworld.pl and remove "use Switch" and replace the use of "switch .. .case ..." with if() ... else () ... 

if you can share the code you'll get better feedback :)